# prevent the execution of function from double click

Tags: jquery

when on button click this function is called

```
save_edit: function() {

    this.do_save();

},
```

I am trying to disable a button once it is clicked to prevent double clicks. How can I do it within this function?

Comment: you mean disable any subequent clicks? or disable just "double-clicks"?

Comment: when button clicked from all un which are executed this fun will executed first.....................and disable subequent clics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#el").click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    // do more stuff
    $(this).prop('disabled',false); // if desired 
});
```

Or, if you have several buttons:

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    // $(this) is a jQuery object of the button that was just clicked
    str_id = $(this).attr('id'); // if you really need the ID itself
    // do more stuff
});
```

Comment: In older version of jquery (< 1:6), you will need to use attr instead of prop.

Comment: This is true; use `$(this).attr('disabled','disabled')` and `$(this).attr('disabled','')` if using older versions of jQuery.

Comment: @TurkeshPatel: I'm not sure what you mean by "get the ID". If you're writing this code, surely you already know the ID? Or are you saying there's more than one button that can be clicked?

Comment: in this post #el is the id of button i think so.............and yes this fun is also can called from other buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#element").dblclick(function(){
   return false;
});

$("#element").click(function(){
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: @TurkeshPatel: it depends on what you're trying to disable dblclick on

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to disable the button, you can stop the method from calling the function for a set peroid of time.

```
save_edit: function() {
    if(this.timer)return;
    this.do_save();
    this.timer = window.setTimeout( function(){}, 300 );  //number of ms before you want another submit to happen
},
```

Comment: thnx for your solution but its not suitable for me

Comment: This style of approach doesnt guarentee preventing do_save from being invoked twice, imagine an async call invoking .save_edit() in a callback, it can happen in parallel... You're "locking" after do_save is initiated, you need to lock before it or you have a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn").one(function(){
  //do stuff once and remove handler
});

$("#btn").dblclick(function(){
   return false;
});
```